# Do we have examples for docker image build --iidfile?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am running a script to build a Docker image. I need to push this image to 2 different repositories with **different tags**. For which I need to capture and store the build ID of the image. 
Docker build [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/) talks about a way to store it in a file using  --iidfile.

Do we have any examples around the same?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need image ID. Just use `docker tag` existing image in your build pipeline to create other "cloned" images. Example:

```
docker build -t repo1/image:tag1 .
docker tag repo1/image:tag1 repo2/image:tag2
docker push repo1/image:tag1
docker push repo2/image:tag2
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
I was missing the docker tag -f parameter as I was using the same tag value for different repositories.